# Delete nodes that satisfy a property

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, trees

I want to write a function that takes as argument a pointer A to the root of a binary tree that simulates a (not necessarily binary) ordered tree.
We consider that each node of the tree saves apart from  the necessary pointers `LC` and `RS`, an integer `number`. The function should traverse all the nodes of the ordered tree and for each node $u$ it should do the following:

If the rightmost child of $u$ in the ordered tree is a leaf, this child should be deleted.

So does this mean that we are given a binary tree like the following?

[image]

And then the corresponding ordered tree will be the following and we want to delete the nodes $C$ and $G$?

[image]

Or have I understood it wrong?

**EDIT**: I wrote the following algorithm:

```
Algorithm(node *A){
  node *p=A,*q=NULL;
  if (p==NULL) return;
  if (p->LC!=NULL){
      q=p->LC;
      if (q->RS!=NULL and q->RS->RS==NULL and q->RS->LC==NULL){
          q->RC=NULL;
      }
      if (q->LC!=NULL) Algorithm(q);
   }
   Algorirthm(q->RC);
}
```

Could you tell me if it is right?

Comment: Your "ordered" tree does not look ordered to me. Can you explain how it is ordered?

Comment: I thought that we do it like that:
$$$$
We take the root, its child is the leftmost node from the next level and the other nodes of this level are the siblings of the leftmost node and so on..
$$$$
Am I wrong? @mrp

Comment: After a bit of reading up in my books, I think you are right. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @mrp A ok... Did you take a look at the algorithm I wrote?

Comment: It looks correct to me, although as far as I can tell, the if-check in line 9 (if (q ->LC!=NULL)) is redundant, since if it is null, the algorithm just does nothing and returns, anyway.